# ionic3 - handle images for different OS and devices

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing a cross platform application (android, IOS, windows) using ionic3 and angular4. Can anybody please let me know how to handle the images for different devices and OS?. Because we need to use different pixels for different OS and different size of devices.